# updating node and npm from npm 6 to 8 and node 14 to 16 or 18 on a react native project , fails on ENOENT

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm, cocoapods, homebrew

Getting an error after running npm install,

It seems that npm is not pathed right for this file or something is cached?

I'm using homebrew and nvm to switch between versions, but the only version that works is node 14 and npm 6.

Need to install the following packages:
pod@0.9.0
Ok to proceed? (y) y

````
npm ERR! syscall chmod
npm ERR! path /Users/me/.npm/_npx/a0ca5f5666585aa2/node_modules/pod/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod '/Users/me/.npm/_npx/a0ca5f5666585aa2/node_modules/pod/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/me/.npm/_logs/2022-08-04T19_23_48_147Z-debug-0.log
npm ERR! code 254
npm ERR! path /Users/me/repos/MyApp/MyMobileApp
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh /var/folders/d2/rdhvx2fd24vbsfrtf3lddq9m0000gq/T/postinstall-a0c95179.sh

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/me/.npm/_logs/2022-08-04T19_23_45_192Z-debug-0.log



```. i get User defaults from command line:
    IDEPackageSupportUseBuiltinSCM = YES

error: Could not delete `/Users/me/repositories/MyApp/ios/build` because it was not created by the build system.
    note: To mark this directory as deletable by the build system, run `xattr -w com.apple.xcode.CreatedByBuildSystem true /Users/me/repositories/MyApp/ios/build` when it is created.
error: Could not delete `/Users/me/repositories/MyApp/ios/build` because it was not created by the build system.
    note: To mark this directory as deletable by the build system, run `xattr -w com.apple.xcode.CreatedByBuildSystem true /Users/me/repositories/MyApp/ios/build` when it is created.

** CLEAN FAILED **
````

Is now something that happens when I run xcodebuild -alltargets clean

Comment: Just use `pm2` directly, this `pod` package last update was 7 years ago .

Answer (score 1):

This may be due to cache. Try below step and check if it works

1. Run `rm -rf ~/.npm`
2. Run `npm cache clean --force`
3. Remove `node_modules` (run `rm -rf node_modules`)
4. Remove `package-lock.json` (run `rm -rf package-lock.json`)

Comment: If I run these commands, it installs old packages from a different branch?

Comment: Did you try with yarn? if not can you check by run `yarn` from root of the project to install packages (if already using yarn try after removing cache by `yarn cache clean`)

Comment: yes i did npm cache clean --force. i found a bit more information. when i run xcodebuild -alltargets clean. i posted above.

Comment: Try this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/67311173/10657559

Answer (score 0):

It happens when **npm install** conflict with peer dependencies

--legacy-peer-deps that ignores all peer dependencies when installing.

So the best approch is to use --legacy-peer-deps

```
npm install --legacy-peer-deps
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?